# Gparted to merge partitions

Tags: 12.04, gparted

I inherited a laptop about a month ago. The drive has some unused space that I would like to be added to Ubuntu. I'm really not comfortable doing this without some direction.

Ubuntu 12.04 is on `sda8`. I would like to add `sda4` and `sda7` to `sda8`.

I can't post an image. The drive look likes this:

```
/dev/sda1    fat16
/dev/sda2    ntfs
/dev/sda4    ext3
/dev/sda3    extended
     /dev/sda5     ext3
     /dev/sda8     ext4
     /dev/sda6     linux-swap
     /dev/sda7     ext4
```

Thanks and I appreciate any help.

Comment: IMHO, it would be simpler to wipe it clean, and then install whatever you want the way you want.

Comment: It's going to be a **very** long and tedious process. As @mikewhatever said, is it possible to just wipe it? If you can't, is it at least possible to move all of your data from `sda5` to `sda4`, then merge `sda5` and `sda7` to Ubuntu, instead of `sda4` and `sda7`?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your your live USB/CD and boot into it, and use gparted to resize your partitions, but there is a decent chance that your bootloader will be broken as  a result of that.

It'll be better if you shrink a desired drive, create an ext4 partition in the new space that you created and follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) guide to move your home folder there.